# Using Redux store data to populate dropdown fields in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am trying to populate dropdown fields in a form component using Redux data that I have in my store.

The below method is for each of my dropdowns which isn't populating as I don't think I am accessing the data correctly. I am trying to get it to iterate it out for the individual values in each of my field objects. Am I going down the correct with this?

```
const populateDropdown (option){

            this.props.fields.{option}.length > 0 &&
            this.props.fields.diveType.map(({diveType}) => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem value={diveType.diveTypeID}>{diveType.diveType}</MenuItem>
                )};
        }
```

I have another method with useEffects and object.keys that I don't know would do the same thing.

```
useEffect(() => {
            // dispatch the action to load fields for each field type
            // once loaded, the changes will be reflected in the fields variable from the useSelector
            Object.keys(fields).forEach(name => dispatch(requireFieldData(name)));
        }, []); // <-- empty array
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem while developing the select input using material-UI. for the solution, I created one separate reusable component for generating select input.

**PopulateDropdown.js**

```
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

/**
 * props.dataList: your redux array of object. set default value is empty array
 * props.mappingOprions: its content title and value for render the MenuItem title and value  
 * props.name: form fielname
 * props.label: input label
 */

const populateDropdown = ({ dataList = [], mappingOptions, name, label }) => {
  const { title, value } = mappingOptions;
  return (
    <FormControl style={{ width: 200 }}>
      <InputLabel id={label}>{label}</InputLabel>
      <Select labelId={label} name={name}>
        {dataList.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem value={item[value]}>{item[title]}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default populateDropdown;
```

**How to use this component**

```
//Custome components
import PopulateDropdown from "./components/PopulateDropdown.js";

// consider this as redux state
const reduxStateData = [
  { diveTypeID: 1, diveType: "type 1" },
  { diveTypeID: 2, diveType: "type 2" },
  { diveTypeID: 3, diveType: "type 3" }
];

// mapping options
/**
 * enter keys (which you wan to render as title and value in dropdown list) as value in title and value
 */
const mappingOptions = { title: "diveType", value: "diveTypeID" };

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PopulateDropdown
        dataList={reduxStateData}
        mappingOptions={mappingOptions}
        name="feildName"
        label="Select div type"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Additional**

You can add `defaultOption` props for populating the dropdown default option like `none` or `select option` Menuitem

codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bose-q3kb0?file=/src/App.js:0-744